# Create a new variable and check if it's null in one if

Tags: java

Can I do something like this?

```
if(variable = class.GetVariable() != null){
    variable.doSomething()
}
```

As I said in the comments I'm doing this with a HttpSession, so my goal is to check if there is a parameter in the session with a specific name and if it is do something.

Comment: Do you only need to check if the variable is null?

Comment: `if((variable = class.GetVariable()) != null){`. Parentheses help.

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana In truth I want to check if the session contains a parameter and if it does I do some code. I just don't want to call the session.getParameter twice because I feel that's a massive waste of resources.

Comment: I think it's duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148580/assign-variable-value-inside-if-statement[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148580/assign-variable-value-inside-if-statement)

Comment: @dawis11 Yes, it seems to be a duplicate of that question, unfortunately I couldn't find it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, so long as `variable` has already been defined and you add additional brackets:

```
Foo variable;
if ((variable = GetVariable()) != null) {
    variable.doSomething();
}
```

You tend not to see this pattern *often* as it's not the most readable, but it is often seen when reading from a `BufferedReader` line by line (as it provides a convenient, quick way to read lines until there aren't any):

```
String line;
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
    //Process each line
}
```

Comment: Using `for` you could inline the definition

Answer (score 1):

`!=` has precedence over `=`, so here  the code means assigning the boolean value resulting from `class.GetVariable() != null` to the `variable` variable :

```
if(variable = class.GetVariable() != null){
...
}
```

That is not what you want.
So enclose the assignment between `()` to set explicitly the precedence :

```
String variable = null; 
if( (variable = class.GetVariable()) != null){
    variable.doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you define the variable first, yes but you must put them in parenties:

```
MyObject variable;
if( ( variable = class.GetVariable()) != null){
    variable.doSomething();
}
```